# UISwipeGestureRecogniser in a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

is it possible to have a UISwipeGestureRecognizer work in a UIScrollView?

I have some UIImageViews that I move with a swipe up or down, but this all needs to be inside a UIScrollView as the content is larger than the window size. So when I try to swipe the UIImageView the whole screen scrolls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me

```
[[scrollView panGestureRecognizer] requireGestureRecognizerToFail:yourSwipeGestureRecognizer];
```

although it only works in ios 5.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the minimumTouches property of the recognizer to be 2 or some other number. I'm not sure of just doing it with one is possible.